# Find $\sin(A)$ and $\cos(A)$ given $\cos^4(A) - \sin^4(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $A$ is located in the second quadrant.

Tags: trigonometry

> Question: Find $\sin(A)$ and $\cos(A)$, given $\cos^4(A)-\sin^4(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $A$ is located in the second quadrant.

Using the fundamental trigonometric identity, I was able to find that:

•　$\cos^2(A) - \sin^2(A) = \frac{1}{2}$

and

• $$ \cos(A) \cdot \sin(A) = -\frac{1}{4} $$

However, I am unsure about how to find $\sin(A)$ and $\cos(A)$ individually after this.

Edit: I solved the problem through using the Fundamental Trignometric Identity with the difference of $\cos^2(A)$ and $\sin^2(A)$.

Comment: Hint: double-angle identity for the second bullet.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\left( \cos(A)+ \sin(A) \right)^2 = 1+2 \sin(A) \cos(A)=\frac{1}{2} \\
\left( \cos(A)- \sin(A) \right)^2 = 1-2 \sin(A) \cos(A)=\frac{3}{2} $$

Take the square roots, and pay attention to the quadrant and the fact that $\cos^4(A) >\sin^4(A)$ to decide is the terms are positive or negative.

**Alternate simpler solution**
$$2 \cos^2(A)= \left( \cos^2(A)+\sin^2(A)\right)+\left( \cos^2(A)-\sin^2(A)\right)=1+\frac{1}{2} \\
2 \sin^2(A)= \left( \cos^2(A)+\sin^2(A)\right)-\left( \cos^2(A)-\sin^2(A)\right)=1-\frac{1}{2} \\$$

Comment: note that squaring is not an eäquivalente forming in mathematics

Answer (score 0):

We can use the double angle identities for cosine to solve the problem.  They are
\begin{align*}
\cos(2x) & = \cos^2x - \sin^2x\\
         & = 2\cos^2x - 1\\
         & = 1 - 2\sin^2x
\end{align*}
You correctly found that 
$$\cos^2A - \sin^2A = \frac{1}{2}$$
where $A$ is a second-quadrant angle.  Substituting $2\cos^2A - 1$ for $\cos^2A - \sin^2A$ yields
$$2\cos^2A - 1 = \frac{1}{2}$$
Solve for $\cos A$, keeping in mind that $\cos A < 0$ in the second quadrant.

Substituting $1 - 2\sin^2A$ for $\cos^2A - \sin^2A$ yields
$$1 - 2\sin^2A = \frac{1}{2}$$
Solve for $\sin A$, keeping in mind that $\sin A > 0$ in the second quadrant.

Alternatively, you could determine $\cos A$, then take its inverse to find $A$, then evaluate $\sin A$.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown 
$$\cos^2(A) - \sin^2(A) = 1/2$$

But we know from an identity that 
$$\cos^2(A) + \sin^2(A) = 1$$

Just add and take square root to get the solution for $\cos(A)$. Use the quadrant information to deduce the sign.